# Xamarin doesn't recognizes that Android 6.0 (API 23) is installed on the Android SDK

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

For some reason even though I have Android 6.0 (API 23) installed Xamarin isn't recognizing it. As you can see on the image below I have the API 23 installed on my SDK.

[image]

I also have installed:

- API 25
- Android Support Repository
- Google USB Driver

Any ideas on how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you double-checked Android SDK location in Tools | Options | Xamarin to make sure 23 is installed in the same platforms folder as 25?

Comment: It seems that the android 23 is installed.. https://s27.postimg.org/xfccw2mup/xamarin2.png

Comment: restart visual studio, clean and build first and then run on the emulator.

Comment: The same error happens when I try to clean the solution/if I try to clean the Android project. Clean is cancelled for the same reason. Btw I also tried to do a manual clean deleting the bin and obj folder, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are pointing to the correct SDK path? From Visual Studio go to Tools - Options - Xamarin - Android Settings. Here you can find the location that Xamarin is using for the SDK. By default the SDK is installed under AppData and your SDK if installed under ProjectFiles. Install 23.3, if you can confirm that the SDK path is correct.

Comment: My Android SDK Location is pointing to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk  \\\\\\\  NDK is pointing to: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e   \\\\\\\\ 

By install 23.3, Do you mean install Android SDK Build Tools 23.0.3? I did but the issue is still happening.

Comment: What I'm finding odd is that on my Android application properties the only option available on the "Compile using Android Version: (Target Framework)" is "Use Latest Platform". I can't change for instance to target the API 25, or 22.

Comment: That is really odd. After you installed 23.0.3 did you restart Visual Studio? You should definitely have all Android installed versions under your compile settings. I am currently running a emulator with 23, and it's working fine. Did you create your emulator with AVD?

Comment: I have seen this issue when targeting the wrong platform. Try changing the platform dropdown to ARM. IK Any CPU should include that but I have had problems when targeting Any CPU instead of the specific platform.

Comment: I tried to reinstall the SDK to my local folder but that didn't fix the issue. @Kasper I tried your suggestion but it didn't work as well. I'll try to reinstall Xamarin..

Answer (score 1):

I would try to confirm all of the following seeing how you have all releases of Marshmellow installed.

1. First confirm that you are pointing to the correct SDK. You can find this location in Visual Studio under Tools -> options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings.

[image: SDK Location]

2. Confirm that you have all versions of Marshmellow (23) installed.

[image: Installed API's]

3. Confirm that your emulator is setup for 23.

[image]

Comment: I did all those steps but the problem is still happening. The only difference is our NDK version. Mine is r10e. I'll update it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Updating the NDK did not make a difference as well :(

Comment: Have you tried to repair visual studio, or uninstalling Xamarin and reinstalling?

Comment: The problem was related to Xamarin's installation. I download VS 2017 and now I'm able to run the solution flawlessly using the same SDK,ADK, etc.. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: No problem. Glad you resolved the issue. Happy coding.